# Is this answer "offensive or repulsive"

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18637110), being told that "readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful."  As someone with a very low tolerance for offensive and/or repulsive posts, I was a bit surprised because:

- The answer was definitely on-topic and was of "reasonable" quality.  (I'm not an expert in the field, but there is nothing specific in the answer that appears to be incorrect to me as a layman, and after looking at the other answers it seems to not contradict anything else said as an answer.)
- There are some links to an off-site resource but those links seem to be relevant to the question and, as they are included in the form of a "signature", those links clearly identify the author's affiliation, so can't really be classed as spam unless the author was posting excessive answers containing those links (which is impossible to tell from a review, or even by looking at the author's profile).

So my questions would be:

- Do other readers find the answer offensive or repulsive and, if so, why?
- Are audits in the low-quality review queue designed to test whether we are correctly checking whether an answer is low-quality, or are the audits designed to test whether we are correctly checking whether a review is an audit?

---

Image of review, including free-hand circle in an unashamedly blatant attempt at garnering sympathy up-votes:
[image]

Comment: The answer is clearly spam. You should have identified it as such and flagged it.

Comment: @RobertLongson But why is it spam?  It doesn't seem to fit the criteria for spam listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor/58035#58035).  Plus, in the VLQ review there is no opportunity to flag as spam even if you want to - you can only flag it as being link-only (which it isn't anyway) and **not spam**.

Comment: Did the question ask for PHP training in Chennai?

Comment: @RobertLongson No, but it did ask for information obtained through basic training.  Following that line of reasoning would mean that all links to MSDN, etc, posted by anyone affiliated with Microsoft in any way (or any contributor to MSDN) would be spam unless the question **specifically** asked for the documentation.

Comment: Dude. That's spam. That's literally spam.  If you don't list this under your definition of spam, you need to pencil it in at the bottom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip) <-- if you're "not an expert in the field" you better abstain of stamping answer as OK

Comment: @gnat This has nothing whatsoever to do with your domain knowledge.  Telling people that don't know what spam is to just skip everything isn't helping them be better reviewers.  No amount of technical expertise would have helped here.

Comment: *Plus, in the VLQ review there is no opportunity to flag as spam even if you want to - you can only flag it as being link-only (which it isn't anyway) and not spam.* Use the first option, which is to delete without comment.

Comment: this has everything to do with one being uncertain whether post is OK or needs deletion @Servy (it just happens that to be certain that it's OK one needs domain knowledge but it's not the point here). One needs to act in review only when they are 100% certain, otherwise they should skip no matter how you twist it. Myself I would probably skip this review (maybe that's why I almost never fail audits)

Comment: (I did about 8x more reviews than you so it's not a matter of laziness or inexperience)

Comment: Either it's spam or it's just very low quality (tending towards gibberish). It certainly doesn't look OK.

Comment: @gnat No, again, **this has nothing to do with domain knowledge**.  The post is spam.  The technical merits of the post **are 100$ irrelevant**.  You could have never heard of PHP in your *life* and you would know how to properly review this post.  The fact that you skip 100% of reviews that you see, even when the post *is clear and obvious spam* means that you simply aren't cut out for reviewing.  If you don't want to review *obvious spam*, that's fine, but don't tell everyone else not to.

Comment: @Servy your tiring repetition of how this spam is _obvious_ doesn't make it such (hint: it isn't, see eg the second comment under this question). As for your attempts to question my proficiency as reviewer or teach me how to do it and what to tell, please note that publicly available stats suggest that I do order of magnitude more reviews than you which makes these attempts look somewhat funny

Comment: @gnat If this *isn't* obvious to you, then *that* is a major problem.  That, and not a lack of subject matter expertise is *actually* the issue.  I never once questioned your proficiency as a reviewer.  I questioned your awful advice of telling everyone to skip every single review, even when the posts are clear spam.  The fact that you don't follow your own advice and don't actually skip the posts that you tell everyone else *they* should skip makes your advice all the more inappropriate.  (And yes, I'm aware that you've reviewed a lot of posts; that *why* I said what I said.)

Answer (score 18):

That looks like a very low-effort attempt at an answer used as cover for a spam link. Note that the question already had several answers from years earlier. The new answer was probably posted by someone who searched for any questions that mentioned certain keywords, then copy/pasted the same spam link to answer all of them.

The signature line really should have been a dead giveaway:

> Regards: PHP Training in Chennai | PHP Training

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer seems to be specifically tailored to the question asked, so that doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @YowE3K The two sentence "answer" portion could have been summarized from the other answers or any number of other resources. Like I said, it's just a cover to slip the spam link past automatic filters.

Comment: Is there any way to tell whether the author posted other answers containing the links?

Comment: @YowE3K A moderator will be able to see deleted posts. Having seen this a thousand times, I'm willing to bet this isn't the only post offering PHP Training in Chennai.

Comment: @YowE3K - there were no other posts from this user, but they only visited the site on one day - the day they posted that spam.

Comment: @ChrisF So a single post by the author, on a non-link-only answer, and which identified the author's affiliation, caused the post to get spam-deleted?!?!  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Bill by the number of times I've seen it, it must be the largest training facility in the world... I imagine it helps having a presumably equally massive cheap refrigerator repair service there too though... :p

Comment: @YowE3K - the answer was to 6 year old question, it barely answers the question and has a link to a site offering training. We see this all the time and it's most definitely spam.

Comment: @YowE3K No offense, but it sounds like you want so badly to not be wrong about this audit that you're willing to let an obvious spam post slide. I'd just let it go.

Comment: @ChrisF If the fact that it is a 6 year old question is relevant to whether the answer is spam or not, has anyone suggested that the review queue audits should show that relevant information to the reviewers.  The audits I have seen have always modified the age of the question so that that will not be taken into account.

Comment: @BilltheLizard My autism makes me insist on doing the right thing.  I was hoping in posting the question that the "answer" would be "yeah, that is a bad audit question because it was incorrectly flagged as spam".  The fact that the answer does not meet the criteria for spam, and yet has been deleted as spam, makes me now want to fight for the author's vindication. :(

Comment: @YowE3K But that is obviously spam. It might not be a great answer to use as a review audit, but it definitely is spam.

Comment: @YowE3K If you still don't accept this is spam, please stop reviewing things.

Comment: @RobertLongson OK :(

Comment: @BilltheLizard This is a *great* answer for a review audit.  This is obvious spam.  If someone can't identify this as spam, we don't want them reviewing.

Answer (score 13):

The question did not ask about PHP training, which would have been off topic if it did.

The preliminary initial text is simply there to fool those not paying enough attention. The real intent of the answer is clearly to advertise  a service, which is clearly and obviously spam.

If you're still unsure how to spot spam hang out in the [Charcoal HQ chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) for a few hours, you'll see a fair few posts that look pretty much identical to this.